# Bootstrap Layout: Default Grid System VS Fluid Grid System

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootstrap template where I have to override css to modify the theme. However, the template is using the default grid system of bootstrap, instead of the fluid grid system that I often use. The fluid grid system makes it easier for me to adjust the rest of the spans (.span12, .span9, etc) without overriding them, since it's dynamic. I just had to change the container size.

However in the default grid system in the bootstrap template (.span12, .container are equal to 1200px), although it's also responsive, I found out the spans have a default fixed value. So when I set-up my css as this:

```
.container {
max-width: 940px;
padding: 0 20px;
}
```

And this seemed to work fine for the rest of the layouts, however when I zoom out and check the website at 1200px, everything goes out in place. I thought I was able to fix it with this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.span12, .container {
    width: 940px;
}

.container {
    padding: 0 20px;
}}
```

But then, the rest of the spans in that layout are still in default fixed width and goes below each other since the container is smaller than before. It doesn't adjust, w/c doesn't happen in fluid grid system (that adjusts smoothly).

For example, in the 1200px resolution, .span3 has a width of 270px still. So when I put four .span3 divs together, this would add up to 1080px. But this CAN'T BE because I only need a width of 940px and padding 20px on the sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have answered that in your question yourself. Just assign a fixed width for span classes too:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.container  {
        width: 940px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

.span3 {
  width: 220px;
}

}
```

Span classes have a default property of margin-left: 20px. So if you put .container ==> padding: 0 20px; it may not fit. For this, you can make first child of span3 class margin-left 0 i.e.

```
.span3:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why does it have to be the first-child of a span?

Comment: 220 * 4 = 880 + 4*20 (margin-left's) = 960.

But your container width is only 940. So in order to fix that you remove the margin-left from the first child.

But my recommendation will be not to put padding in container in the big screen but only for small devices i.e for tablets and below. Because in this phase usually the spans gets 100% width. So it is easier for you to control it.

Comment: Because I needed a width of 980px and the design requires a padding of 20px on the left and right. And the spans has a margin-left: 30px in 1200px. But thanks for your answer. I guess I was just being stupid, I thought I should not override the smaller span classes (I'm used to the fluid grid doing that work for me). :)